# How to compare only dates in linq?

Tags: linq

In linq how can i diffentiate the date, like in sql we use 
         datediff(mm,getdate(),getdate())=0
  now how can i write in linq, can any body help me thank you.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly, but you can extract the date part by calling the Year, Month, Day, etc method on DateTime Objects ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx ).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
var query = from entity in entities
            where entity.SomeDateTime.Date == anotherDateTime.Date
            select entity;
```

This only compares dates and not times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for comparing two dates using linq in C#

```
            DateTime d1 = myDate1;
            DateTime d2 = myDate2;
            TimeSpan t1 = d2.Subtract(d1);
            totalDays = t1.Days;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special in Linq about date and time handling, so we should look at the plain .Net facilities.

A `DateTime` in C# is a date and time.

To get just the date component in C#, try this:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // or DateTime.Now for local time/day
DateTime today = now.Date;
```

This will give you the date and time at midnight of the same day.

If you want to get the difference in days between two `DateTime` objects:

```
public TimeSpan DiffDates(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return d1.Date - d2.Date;
}

// ...

if(DiffDates(dateTime1, dateTime2) == TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternately you could check directly if the dates are equal:

```
if(dateTime1.Date == dateTime2.Date)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you skip the `.Date` property, then you will get incorrect results.